# Why is "looking for a job" so obsessed with London?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

I live in a reasonably rural part of North Wales. I like living where I live it's nice and quiet and I get to climb mountains

The one place I would hate to live is **London**. Many people love the place, but personally, I'm a country boy, I like the country....Also, It's noisy and dirty, miles away from any mountains and no one speaks welsh.

I have my location set in my profile:

[image]

for those not familiar with the geography of North Wales I live a long way away from London:
[image]

Now, to the nub of my irritation. Why oh why am I **bombarded with Jobs in London everyday!!**

[image]

There are some (admittedly not loads of) jobs considerably nearer:

[image]

So why focus on the London ones! I can count the amount of jobs outside of London this has shown me on one hand. Just because I'm in the UK, this does not mean I want to work in London!

### In seriousness

Surely this algorithm can be more intelligent than it is now?

SO is trying to sell this service more and more. I get that they want to monetise the site. My point is, give me some relevant content, I might use it. Right now, it's not relevant.

Comment: I see that you recently posted a question about London. Would you be interested in job openings in London?

Comment: So the side bar is sold to the highest bidder? why would I want to participate in SO careers then? I thought SO was supposed to make the internet a better place. If I wanted to get offered jobs I wasn't interested in I'd spend more time on linked in.

Comment: BTW I'm within driving distance of two of the UKs biggest cities (Liverpool and Manchester). I've worked in both in the past. I work for a FTSE 250 company. This isn't exactly outer Mongolia. There are several very rich, very large employers within the vicinity. So I don't really buy into the "no companies are prepared to pay where you live" argument.

Comment: I live in the US and I have seen ads in the sidebar for London as well... do you have the 'remote' option enabled on Careers?

Comment: I don't think so @JoshCrozier. That said, I can't find a remote option..?!

Comment: @Liam I don't know if it's related to the ads that are displayed, but the 'remote' option is visible when editting your CV under "Job Status" -> http://i.stack.imgur.com/dNwh0.png

Comment: the Stackoverflow careers advert and the stackoverflow careers web page (that it takes you too when you click on it) aren't linked...o_O Seriously?! How does this make the internet a better place.

Comment: @JoshCrozier no, not ticked.

Comment: I just double checked my sidebar on the main site. One job ad is located one state over and the other is on the opposite end of the country. 4hr 20min and 16hr away respectively. (Then again, I don't have a Careers profile, so there wouldn't be anything telling them whether or not I want to move anyway.)

Comment: At first I thought this was going to be a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46433/france-is-not-within-30-miles-of-london

Comment: I work for a British firm in Prague. We're connected through, you know, London, and I'm getting the ads, too. I can be there in a half of your time, but I need a plane: http://i193.photobucket.com/albums/z176/echoroba/screenshots/prg-ldn.png~original

Comment: @choroba: Are you hiring? ;)

Comment: I actually had no idea that IP geolocation could be this inaccurate.

Comment: @PreferenceBean: Actually, I'm leaving :)

Comment: *I get to climb mountains* -- Pictures or it's all lies

Comment: @BhargavRao Look at the first revision: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/317071/1

Comment: @Josh That's some normal hooman climbing. Liam's a bear! :D (Jokes apart, he could've kept that image, tho it's irrelevant :( )

Comment: I spent a couple weeks in Henley-on-Thames once.  Sent my wife and sister-n-law on a two week tour London, Cardiff and Edinburgh last year.  I'd love to relo the family to anywhere in the UK for a couple years if the right job would just come along.

Comment: Maybe there are lots of jobs in London? I'm in Wellington and it frequently says Auckland.

Comment: I finally installed AdBlock (after years of considering it) because I told Facebook specifically that I had an MBA (from a decent state school), and they kept showing me ads for business schools/MBA programs (of lower quality!)

Comment: @BhargavRao you could also check my [outdoors.se profile](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/users/2766/liam?tab=profile) :)

Comment: @immibis  They're both in Australia, so what are you complaining about? ;)

Comment: @Liam then why if I am from Romania (city Baia Mare), I'm seing jobs from Iasi, Bucharest, Cluj-Napoca (Romania) and London (UK)?

Comment: Climbing wet rocks under the rain. At least you're no liar: You are indeed Welsh!

Comment: Honestly, 4 hours away is a lot closer than the jobs that show up for me, living in the U.S. Besides, people looking for jobs might be willing to relocate, so it's not like it should only show jobs within 30 minutes of your house or something.

Comment: Move to Llanfairpwllgwyngyll...

Comment: As much as I love SO, I always try to ignore that crap in the sidebar. But guess what, that's how I ended up reading this question. This is hopefully the last time I get click baited by "Hot Meta posts"

Comment: Wow you got the internet in Wales!

Comment: I would also love an option to set the place you want the ads to show you. I might live in London but that doesn't mean I would be interested in another London based job.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

At the moment we target jobs based on IP, and yours geo-locates to London...

Not ideal, and we love the idea of taking actual profile location into account if known, but it may still be a while before we're there. It's on our radar though!

Comment: You...use.... IP.... address o_O but......that's......oh well.

Comment: For the vast majority of anonymous users, it's the best data we can use. But you're right: for users where we actually know your location (because you _told us_), we should be using that information instead. We're working on getting that put in place.

Comment: Easy solution, get a VPN so you can spoof your location as North Wales!

Comment: Incidentally, I had the same question back in 2011, though I asked on Stack Exchange meta. (["I like the idea of showing jobs by one’s profile location first, and falling back to IP geo, we’ll implement soon"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94864/why-does-careers-list-jobs-near-worcester-on-my-homepage)!)

Comment: I would wager for people actually interested in a job, you won't have trouble getting a self-reported location. You can always fall back on the 85%-accurate IP geolocation technology.

Comment: @MattGibson So "soon" apparently means "not within the next half-decade at least" in SE terms. Good to know.

Comment: If you track and profile people's habits and location, they complain. If you don't, they complain. (xD)

Comment: @IanKemp A hundred years may be defined as "soon", depending on the scale... :P

Comment: @DanielParejoMuñoz This is the worst of both worlds. I'm volunteering my correct location to the system, and it's then ignoring that information, tracking me by IP and getting the answer wrong...

Comment: @MattGibson hahaha, I know! It's so ironic it's even funny! X'D

Comment: A search filter that gives a specific radius would be good. And a search filter that is 'not within 20 miles of central london' would be lovely.

Comment: 5 years is not soon in Internet time.

Comment: @Sobrique: once you have a radius filter, simply set it to "within 24881 miles of the antipodal point of Charing Cross" ;-) Might have to adjust the number a bit for the varying circumference measured along different great circles.

Comment: @IanKemp tyically "soon" means [6 to 8 weeks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/293462)

Comment: @DrewJordan that's only for physical delivery.  Software implementation is 6 to 8 years.

Comment: This is also why I used to occasionally be shown jobs on the wrong *continent*. Once I set up a location it got a lot better. For the last couple of weeks it's been showing me the ad for a job at the company I'm working for, doing the job I already do, because we're currently hiring for someone to fill the empty desk next to mine. I guess that means the ad targeting works?

Comment: @anaximander - Sounds like a job you'd be qualified for. Maybe try applying and see if you can get a raise.

Comment: Maybe Korneel should post a question on StackOverflow asking how to change the SO codebase to prioritise the user provided location before the Geo-IP location:-) Five years sounds a bit long for this kind of change, especially when clients pay for geo-targeting.

Comment: @anaximander Or they're looking to replace you with someone cheaper...

Comment: My IP geo-locates to Southampton (where I am), but still I only see jobs in London.

Comment: If it works based on location, which is user-definable, I will most certainly be putting my location to Wales. Working my 60k job in London and seeing ads for 25k jobs in Treuddyn will bring a smile to my face.

Only kidding, i'm a PhD student on $2.70 an hour. fml.

Comment: Don't forget that I can buy a (good sized) house for £200K or less... @JJ

Comment: Using IP geolocation sounds like an invitation for employers who don't want you advertising relevant jobs to their staff to prevent that.

Comment: Bit unsettling that something that is so prominent on every SO page is not treated with more respect. That being said, the tracking seems to work for me, there are just no relevant jobs where I am :'(

Comment: I would like a filter that is flexible: the higher the salary the more far away I would be willing to move. So where can I specify additional miles / k dollars?

Comment: @pabrams Physical delivery changed to [6-8 months](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272623/184030) instead of weeks recently.

Comment: I realise this is already answered, but the jobs sidebar is currently showing me jobs from Bristol and Pontefract. These places are 200 miles apart. It usually shows London. However, I live in the North UK which is around 300 miles from London. All geolocation services I tried place me within 5 miles of where I actually live. how can you get it so wrong?

Comment: Is this now fixed? Or has my ip address changed?