# Where can I enter tech I know on developer story if I didn't use that on previous positions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, developer-story

I was checking the developer story, and I can't find a place where I can enter information about the tech I know, e.g.

C, C++, C#, .NET, etc.

Now indeed I can add tech to the positions I had. But what if I know a tech say React.js, but haven't used it in any of the positions I held before?

Lack of this feature seems problematic to me - because using that CV I can't apply to places which require some tech which I know, but haven't used in previous positions.

E.g. we could let users create custom sections where they could put stuff like this.

Comment: There is no "we", the company sets the format and has as yet shown no interest in changing it.  Most objections were discussed in [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336296/what-if-im-not-rear-admiral-grace-hopper-but-a-regular-developer-what-does-de).

Comment: @HansPassant hm didn't go through all posts there but still think ability to create custom section would be useful, without bringing much harm

Answer (score 2):

You have some alternatives depending on *how* you did learn these technologies:

- Did you use these in a side project of yours, or while contributing to an open source project? Then add *Open Source* and/or *Feature or Apps* items.
- Were you taught it in university or anywhere else? Then add *Education* or *Certification* items.
- Lastly, there's the *Milestone* item type for general accomplishments that don't fit in any of the other item types. You could use it with a category of "Self-learning" or the like, and "Learned C++ by doing XXX" as the title/description.

Comment: Just "Milestone" - requires a date, which doesn't really fit in this case. Don't you agree? (e.g. if I list many tech, I'd need to put a date with large timeframe :))

Comment: Just add the approximate date in which you felt like you were comfortable enough with the technology to make it worth adding to your Story, you can then add more details in the summary as you find appropriate (e.g. "It took me X months to learn Y").

Comment: OK the date requirement still makes it cumbersome to use, e.g. if I wanna add ASP MVC, react, etc. which I learned in different times, e.g. ASP in 2013, react in 2016, then I need to add a range like 2013-2016... which might be confusing...  custom section would easily solve the issue though, or making the date non required field.