# Allow Job Matches to exclude locations

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

When I specify my Job Match preferences, I can list places I would like to work. I can't specify places I would prefer not to work.

For instance - I'm a UK resident. It's a small country, and I'm willing to relocate pretty much anywhere within in it. However, London is a big city with high living costs; I did that when I was younger, now I've got a family I don't want to do it again.

Please enhance the match preferences so I can say "Want to work in: United Kingdom". "Don't want to work in: London".

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. We'll keep this in mind for future development.

Comment: Very related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317071/why-is-looking-for-a-job-so-obsessed-with-london

Answer (score 2):

I agree that this would be a useful feature. At the moment, I have to set up an email rule to delete 90% of Stack Overflow job emails that are about London, since I don't want to work there.