# Announcing the New Salary Calculator

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs, salary-calculator

A little over a year ago, we launched [How We Pay](https://stackoverflow.com/company/salary/calculator), an interactive tool that shows how much you'd earn if you worked at Stack Overflow. We believe that developers should have as much information as possible when looking for a job - this includes salaries. Being [transparent with developer, product manager, and designer salaries at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/07/27/salary-transparency/) was a way for us to be public with that data.

Today, we're launching a [new Salary Calculator](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/salary) for developers to discover their earning potential and build their careers. This new calculator allows you to see where you compare with others in your role and location, and will give you greater insight when either looking for a new job or evaluating your current one.

Using the data from the 2017 annual survey, we'll calculate a salary range based on parameters submitted. You will be able to search salaries for any given role, location, education, experience, and even specific technologies.

[image: salary calculator]

Based on the amount of data we received in the survey results, the initial release has limited salaries to the United States, Canada, the United Kingdom, France, and Germany. There are more details [available on the blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/09/19/much-developers-earn-find-stack-overflow-salary-calculator/), in the Geography section.

While the data used to create the calculator is from the 2017 annual survey, we've created a way for you to help improve it by providing your current salary. You can be sure that anything you share with us about your salary is completely confidential - it will never be shown on your profile or shared with employers - providing it is totally voluntary and not required to use the tool.

If you want to know about the methodology and the model used in the calculator, head over to the [blog where Julia Silge goes into detail](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/09/19/much-developers-earn-find-stack-overflow-salary-calculator/) about how this was done. In the meantime, if you run into any bugs with the new calculator, please [post here on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com) and tag it with [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) and [salary-calculator](/questions/tagged/salary-calculator). As always feedback is welcome, so try out the calculator and let us know what you think!

---

**Update: 2017-09-22**

We've received a lot of feedback about the UK/EUR salaries appearing to be incorrect, based on that feedback Julia reviewed the model and found there was a bug with how we were doing the currency conversion. This has been fixed and a new version of the calculator has been released.

Comment: Not many countries are available, it seems. :(

Comment: China not in the list. :(

Comment: For information about the supported countries, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356750/the-location-selector-doesnt-let-me-choose-my-country

Comment: @Cœur There are more details about the countries included [in the blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/09/19/much-developers-earn-find-stack-overflow-salary-calculator/) under the geography section.

Comment: Why is the CSS tag not available for "frontend developer"? Why can't we just write in whatever tech we want?

Comment: the blog doesn't help people in the South Pacific. Disappointed, might have been prudent to wait and include more places.

Comment: @TylerH The technologies used in the modeling are the ones that were part of the [2017 Developer Survey](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2017#technology) questions, because that's the data we have available!

Comment: @JuliaSilge I feel like I recall reporting that CSS should be on that list as well; IIRC I had to manually type it in on the survey. So you should have at least *one* entry for CSS in that data ;-)

Comment: HINT: in the calculator, use a FAKE country first, then you get a survey that allows you to add your REAL country in the future.

Comment: What means the [percentile](https://imgur.com/kVeMMPa)? I know what percentile is [(hopefully)](https://www.dict.cc/deutsch-englisch/Durchschnittswert.html), but what is a 25th percentile, 50th percentile, 75th percentile?

Comment: Ah, never mind. In case anyone is wondering, [here is the answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/74335/205022)

Comment: This tool is great! Fantastic job guys :)
Another thing I love is that we can help expanding the database by adding and updating _our own_ salary, so not only "static" data are included in calculations.

Comment: The numbers here are rather interesting, at least for UK, and specifically my location (Newcastle upon Tyne). For example, as a C# backend developer with zero years experience one should be earning £39,000. So almost £40k for someone with zero experience? That's impossible! So it's a good tool but really needs some work I think.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me I'm underpaid

Comment: Where is the dropdown option for embedded developer?  This role is mentioned as #3 in the article, but not available in the dropdown for the calculator.

Comment: Once again, this tool seems to be overpaying people. Also - Is this a Work in Progress?? There is no Title "Data Analyst" only "Data Scientist". This seems like a big gap. The optional tags seem lacking - `excel` is not a tag choice? and what about other "non-coding" platforms like Tableau or SSIS? (this post is coming from a Data Analysts perspective)

Comment: @MattR Yes, it is a work in progress. The initial release was based on the 2017 developer survey data and we'll be adjusting from there.

Comment: Nice tool i suggest to include some other information like :

 - Companies (Google, Microsoft, Nokia, Samsumng..)

Comment: @bluefeet, A suggestion would be to have some "sick graphs" showing the salary trajectory if you had more experience or higher education? that could definitely be a data-driven possibility with the survey data. It would also be a nice touch and motivate people to continue their learning (AKA: keep using SO to learn more ;) ) #YouCanPayMeLater

Comment: The salary figures seem to be ambiguous. Lack of countries is a drawback.

Comment: It would be nice if SO jobs could have "Reviews" of the workplaces from fellow SO'ers (kind of like glassdoors but local to programmers)...

Comment: Seems to be underpaying by quite a bit, based on my experience.

Comment: I noticed a small bug in the calculator. The "Years of experience" input [allows for negative values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBJVD.png).

Comment: @stybl we're not doing client-side validation... if you submit with -42 years of experience, you should see an error message when you submit the form... can you confirm that's the case?

Comment: @g3rv4 Yes, the error appears after submitting.

Comment: The dropdown doesn't have Embedded developer, despite it being #3 in the graphic in the article.  And, of course, it's what I need.  Big fail.  Suggestion:  Add an "other" option to both role and country.  They're not a useful selection, but at least you can progress past the first screen.

Comment: I am very disappointed that Australia is not in the list. We're an important first-world country too! :'(

Comment: This post should be visible to the people who are living in the listed countries.

Comment: @SankarRaj To the best of my knowledge, there's no support for such a thing on SE. Implementing it just for this would be way overkill.

Comment: One major thing this is missing, is that salaries are generally higher in big cities than in the rest of the country. Mostly this is because living in big cities cost more - the actual net salary probably ends up roughly the same. But the amount on the pay check can be quite different depending on where in the country you live.

Comment: I find this a bit gimmicky. Speaking as the difference in what is and what isn't a decent salary can vary well over 50% between where in that country you live, this seems like it's not that useful

Comment: So, if I moved to the US I'd be earning at least 4x my salary, wow I'm underpaid

Comment: Could we add quant developer as a category as well please?

Comment: More countries must be added like (India, Australia, China etc.). Developers from other countries are also contibuting well in this world.

Comment: @Bhavin As mentioned in the blog [_"We know there are other countries, such as India, where there are huge numbers of professional developers who contribute both to the Stack Overflow community and technology in the world in general; we are exploring the possibilities of expanding our calculator to more countries like these."_](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/09/19/much-developers-earn-find-stack-overflow-salary-calculator/)

Comment: I mean if you can't get it accurate in a country with a population of 65 million I hate to think what's going to happen in a country with 1.3 Billion!

Comment: No "Hungary" as an option so this is not helpful to me much

Comment: The homepage popover is pretty annoying. It's great that you have this data and are sharing it, but overlaying questions on the homepage is a frustrating experience. A big orange "New" box that's just an ad is bad enough, but the auto-popover behavior is really inconvenient.

Comment: @dimo414 the "new feature" announcement was just implemented and it will be used for more announcements on the site. See this MSO post for more details - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356853/426671 the salary calculator was just the first thing being announced via the feature.

Comment: @bluefeet The only thing that NEW thing does is annoy me because the calculator only supports a very few countries. Wait what, we can type our country now? And enter our salary if our country isn't supported? _When did this happen??_

Comment: @bluefeet Should we be entering our pay before or after tax? That makes a big difference.

Comment: @Clonkex I believe I mentioned in my post that we were asking users to provide their salary information to help us get additional data. Your salary would be the amount before tax.

Comment: @bluefeet Indeed you did, but when I first opened the calculator yesterday I was given a limited list of countries from which to choose, and no way to input my own country. That has changed and I can now type Australia and then input my current salary. Luckily I guessed right and put my salary in before tax :)

Comment: There are many other designations,then the dropbox has provided. For eg. Associate software developer.

Comment: I can't help you get more data because there's no category for embedded developer.

Comment: So apparently the median salary for a back-end developer with 0 years experience (in London) is £57,000?

Comment: For @a505999 and others who are interested, the embedded/devices developer is now available as an option; thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @DavidG Based on the feedback on the UK/EUR salaries we did some investigating and found a bug in the currency conversion. They have just released a new version of the calculator with the conversion corrected.

Comment: Broken on mobile browser (chrome iOS). "Enter up to 5 supported tags."

Comment: @adrichman Please [ask a new question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) on MSO and tag it with `bug` and `salary-calculator`.

Answer (score 56):

I don't know how useful this calculator is. For me, the calculated salary is too low. Others in the comments say that it's too high. In any case, one needs to decide for oneself what salary is right - the calculator can't really help.

In all three companies I worked for, just judging the salary from a single competence was impossible. I always see at least three things that come together:

- skills in software industry
- skills in your company's industry, be it automotive, transportation, medicin, automation, ...
- soft skills

The calculator only considers the software industry.

So, to me, the calculator does not give anything I could not read from the survey results. If developers are not capable of reading such survey results, a lower salary is probably ok ;-)

Comment: I was just going to post a comment back about the industry: One of my Data Projects was to use the Indeed API and to build a predictive model on "fit" of the job description and also its salary. You'd be surprised the difference in salary based on field (ie, healthcare vs. FinTech). Also there is a high jump after a few years of experience. the variance after 10 years is much more volatile than say someone with only a few years. Also depends on position title, director, manager, CIO, etc.

Comment: My first thought when seeing this was to post it to our Slack Random channel. But fortunately I calculated my salary first and realized I don't want the boss to know that I'm underpaid according to the survey. Decided it's a better career move to not tell anyone about it.

Comment: This may point to a good question for next year's survey: How long have you been coding in your industry? Personally I work in a somewhat high learning curve domain. Part of the reason I was hired for my current position was that I was a good developer but also because I understood a significant amount about the domain. That being said there are some pure software companies where this isn't relevant

Comment: @mason under or over paid? If I was under what the calculator said I'd definitely post it hoping for a raise! :D

Comment: @CalvT븃 It said I was overpaid. I make nearly 50% more than what it said I should be making.

Comment: It doesn't take into consideration if a person is a company full-time employee, self-employed contractor (like myself), or consultant (which I aim to be one day).  I know I make much more than a full-time employee, so I'm sure my salary skews the average.

Answer (score 50):

**Update:** Seems the currency issue was a big contributor to the below. I'm leaving this here; one just to show what was happening and two because I still think it's flawed to treat entire countries as a single place.

---

So my salary is low according to this, by low I mean at least half (25th percentile) if not a third (75 percentile)! I've been involved in recruitment for multiple companies and I've worked in this industry for 15 years in the North West of the Uk. There is no way on earth I could earn that amount of money where I live. No jobs are advertised within 100 miles of me where I could earn that amount of money (on SO jobs or elsewhere). So **I would say something has gone badly wrong in your figures here**. They don't seem to add up to anything matching my experiences.

I'd say at least one major problem here is you seem to be treating the UK (**65 million people!**) as one place. It's obviously very diverse. My guess is that your figures are very skewed towards major metropolitan areas and especially London ([I've discussed SO Jobs obcession with London before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317071/why-is-looking-for-a-job-so-obsessed-with-london)).

Now I live in North Wales, But I'm within commuting distance of the cities of Manchester(3<sup>rd</sup> biggest city in the UK) and Liverpool(7<sup>th</sup> biggest), not to mention the M6 belt where lots of large tech firms are based. Doing a quick search on SO jobs (and others) to within 100 miles of me I can't really find a job paying much more than what I'm on now. **So where are all these incredibly well paying jobs?** I'd like to show these to my boss at my next pay review?!

I'm guessing that's why the areas are so broad? Did you not have enough of a distribution to produce figures for smaller areas?

To help put these figures into perspective it'd be nice to see a distribution of where the respondents reside within a geographical area? My guess is that they would be heavily skewed towards the South East of the UK.

Comment: It's probably just Jon Skeet skewing the averages as normal.

Comment: It's like estimating the mass of a marble (me) on the sun (Jon) :)

Comment: The figure I got was ridiculously high too.

Comment: 50% says their salary is too high, 50% says their salary is too low. People will never learn that _one man's meat is another man`s poison_.
:)

Comment: I live and work on the UK south coast and think I get paid pretty fairly for what I do.  However the calculator suggests I am *vastly* underpaid.  I would have to work in London to get anywhere near the salaries quoted.

Comment: I'm the same way -- I can't imagine anyone in my location earning in the 75% for what was reported for me. I'm pretty sure I'm earning more than most in my area, yet I was about $5k below the 25th percentile number. Maybe I need to ask for a raise!

Comment: Not only it pays better in huge city because of the cost of living, but you have different kind of company. In France there are some companis that pretty much expect you to give up any social life (wel call it "american like" wheter it's true or not) and pay way more than the others for that ( a project manager will earn like 60k€ while you won't have 50k€ for the same level in "classic" companies). Services industry pay usually better than industrial companies, but big industries have often way better benefits.

Comment: But I still think the calculator is not useless, in big city if you're confident enough you could aim for the 25% quartile, in lower city with less salary, you could still expect the 75% quartile.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. This along with several of the other comments made us review the UK/EUR data and we found a bug in the currency conversion. They have just deployed a fix which should correct the issue.

Comment: Ah now that is much better. What currency we're you converting to Tanzanian Shillings?! I know the £ is pretty rubbish these days but I don't think it's that bad! :)

Answer (score 32):

I find this amusing.

It seems this isn't really a good way for Software Developers or Software Engineers to find their salaries:

[image]

[image]
[image]

I think what it shows is that this calculator is heavily biased towards tech startupy types of companies, given that it doesn't even have Software Developer/Engineer as job titles..

Comment: As I mentioned in my [comment to George](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356746/announcing-the-new-salary-calculator/356887#comment515723_356772), the roles are currently aligned with the predefined items in Jobs.

Comment: Why can't we suggest new ones? Why can't we suggest technologies that aren't listed?

Comment: @bluefeet oh gosh that means SO is contributing to the buzzword spam of "full stack developer" too? :(

Comment: I also would like to suggest Software Engineering as a role. This is way more precise in terms of calculating median salaries than "full stack developer"

Comment: If you're interested, [this answer goes into detail](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356958/426671) about where the list of roles came from.

Comment: @enderland  ...what?   _"Software Developer"_ and _"Software Engineer"_  - these are the actual buzzwords here. Zero meaning whatsoever.

Answer (score 20):

Minor thing... Why does it even let you select an experience level `< 1`?

[image]

Granted it warns you after you hit submit, just seems like something that you shouldn't be allowed to do in the first place.

The placeholder text states: `0-20+` and allows you to go lower. Please fix :-)

Comment: SO where Javascript validation hasn't been invented yet

Comment: As _g3rv4_ [said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356746/announcing-the-new-salary-calculator?cb=1#comment515716_356746) already: **it's server-side validated**, that means You cannot submit negative value.

Comment: If you have just begun studies at university, then you might have up to -5 years of experience, I suppose :)

Answer (score 8):

Since the Netherlands is not available, I choose to check the calculator for Germany. As far as I know the salaries are bit higher there, but not by much.

But I feel the "Years experience" is more an "Inflation salary increase bonus". I toggled all options a bit and they seem to add about 3% per year, no matter you education level or field. It roughly translates to about 100 euro a month for the first 10 years.

Now that may be true if you stick around the same company forever, but you'll advance more if you switch around more often. I think that's the main reason some say the results are higher and other say it's lower.

I get a lot of job offers and went to a few interviews, and most often they offer at least a €500 increase per month if you have something to offer. Convincing your own boss to give you a 500euro raise is tough, but convincing somebody that wants you is a lot easier. Especially if you already have a job and can set some demands.

I also noticed that companies that need to dispatch you to their customers, are much more concerned about your education. They need you to have papers to be able to sell you to their clients and thus a degree is worth a lot. If you interview with companies that need you for their own software, they are more interested in your actual experience.

This also doesn't show other benefits. I have friends that earn less, but do get a company car and basically all the gas they require, even for personal use. In the end they have more to spent than me, because I have to pay for it myself.

My advice: If it's your first job, go for something where you can learn a lot and are not some small part of a massive machine where you constantly do the same thing. This might be a smaller company that pays less, but the broader experience is gold.
Then if you want the big money, don't be shy to look around after a while (not every month) and sell yourself for more money.

But no matter where you are: **You'll have to prove yourself, if you want more money**.

And to be honest, most developers I have met the past 10 years, are simply very basic. They get things to work usually, but don't ask how. And "10 years experience" often means they learned something 10 years ago, and are still doing the same thing over and over again.

Answer (score 7):

One of the issues I'm finding while using it is that I can't add a new Job Title and add my own salary in there; For instance `Solutions Architect` does not exist as a job title (neither does 'Architect').  I haven't tried `Archillitect` yet.

Comment: The list of roles is currently the same as the list presented under search jobs > search filters > background when looking for jobs. The goal is to eventually expand this list.

Comment: The heck is a "solutions architect" anyway? Sounds incredibly vague. Do you work with chemistry?

Comment: @Lundin I have exactly the same title here in France. This means I'm responsible to create software architectures and implement the basics so the developers can start developing. I develop too, but this title means you have the big picture of the whole software solution because basically you design it.

Comment: @ken2k I can guess what it is supposed to mean, since I do such work too. My title for that would be software engineer, or possibly software designer. Emphasis on software, not "solutions". Otherwise, someone who does the same kind of design work in electronics, machinery or any other similar branch would also be a "solutions architect". Notably, in many countries the titles engineer or architect would require a diploma. I am a diplomated compturer engineer, but I'm not a diplomated architect. The latter would require me to study building construction, see.

Comment: @Lundin I see your point, but "solution architect" is valid though for software design. See for instance https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/solutions/architecture/ Basically it's the person that is responsible for the design of "Azure solution architectures"

Answer (score 7):

The results seem low to me as well -- compare with the existing "How we pay" [calculator](https://stackoverflow.com/company/salary/calculator) for a hypothetical ;-) engineer:

[image: How we pay]

vs

[image: Salary calculator]

I get that SO is an awesome employer, and values their employees well above the average, but there does seem to be a bit of a discrepancy here...

I can say that I would consider even the 75th centile value to be a bit of an undervaluation; the results for US based developers also display quite a big gap at first glance.

I haven't read this year's salary survey yet, but don't recall feeling like the 2016 version was an underestimate, so maybe there is some bug with the calculator itself?

Comment: I found the salary results for those who identify as data scientists in our Developer Survey interesting as well, and perhaps modestly surprising. When I dug into this deeper during analysis, I think the explanation is that developers are choosing the label "data scientist" more often than the past, and when they are doing data work at some level, either data engineering or data analysis. I'm not too interested in gatekeeping about this label (WILL THE REAL DATA SCIENTIST PLEASE STAND UP) but developers using the label broadly or aspirationally has shifted the salary a bit in this dataset.

Comment: Interesting-- I looked at this years survey now & that seems like a reasonable conclusion -- no doubt "DS" is a terrible & ill specified title at the best of times! I wonder if you would get away with some questions probing daily activities as an adjunct to the self assessed title -- I imagine similar issues could crop up with things like "DevOps" or "DB admin" which could mean wildly different things to different people. Or "Full Stack dev", which has somehow become sort of aspirational lately as well...

Comment: One other thing to note with your specific example here is that the Stack Overflow "How We Pay" calculator uses years in a given job title (so, for me, the years I have been a data scientist) while the Developer Survey/Salary Calculator uses years coding professionally (which for me is 3-4x higher).

Comment: @JuliaSilge hi, thank you for your article, but can you avoid capitalizing each word in the title? It should be "_How much do developers earn? Find out …_"

Comment: @Cœur That's the editorial style guide for Stack Overflow blog posts; [they're all title case](https://stackoverflow.blog/insights/).

Answer (score 7):

Pointless as all the previous salary calculators outside of the US.

First the job titles are amusingly biased ad reported by @enderland (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356887/870604) and @George Stocker (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356772/870604). In case you don't know, not everyone works for either a startup or as a web developer....

As for the numbers... still plain wrong. I'm not even in the 25th percentile (I'm working in France, not in Paris).

I'm confused about why SO keeps wasting resources to design such calculators.

Oh sorry I think I got it, it's so they can say "look you're underpaid, but hey here's a link to our wonderful job list, click on it !"...

Comment: Based on the feedback on the UK/EUR salaries we did some investigating and found a bug in implementing currency conversion. We have just released a new version of the calculator with corrected conversions.

Comment: It is almost as pointless for US too because it covers only the lowest level everywhere except data scientist. Say if you are a bad or not-interested in your job programmer working for it department somewhere - here is what you can expect over years.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: since the fix, the values seem more in line with the real data, though non-London values are I think still a bit on the higher end, but by a much smaller margin. London data however became a bit on the lower end, at least for my searches.

Old post: Although you do differentiate between areas in the US, it looks like there is nothing similar done for the UK, although the salaries here vary wildly between London and larger metropolitan areas in England, and the other countries (Scotland, Wales, NI). Based on a few checks, and checking against the actual salaries reported in the Job finder (and glassdoor + personal experience), for the UK based salaries you can use the following method to get a better result:

- 75th percentile: good paying London based job
- 50th percentile: average paying London based job, good paying in other metropolitan English areas
- 25th percentile: poor paying London based job, average for other English metropolitan areas, good paying in other UK areas

Obviously it would be better to have an area based search, or at least have a way to remove London/South East based values from the search results, that would make the tool much more useful for people searching jobs outside of London

Comment: Based on the feedback on the UK/EUR salaries we did some investigating and found a bug in the currency conversion. They have just released a new version of the calculator with the conversion corrected.

Comment: @bluefeet thanks, looks much better for London, it still looks a bit overpriced for non-London, but by a much smaller margin

Comment: Great news, those sneaky little bugs are just terrible. Thanks again for the feedback on this it helped us figure out what was going on.

Answer (score 3):

The list of tags for languages/frameworks/platforms is too small. I understand that you probably don't have enough data for other tags, and that's okay.

However, when I submit my own salary I am confined to using those pre-existing tags. They don't really match me, so you will end up with bad data. So I propose that **when adding your salary, the list should be expanded** and allow for new technologies.

Answer (score 3):

Do you consider work hours? In Germany working for engineering industry results in 35h/week. Other industries have 40h/week. What about salary of part time developers?

Answer (score 0):

I just have searched for a word "tax" on this page, as well as on the blog page by Julia Silge that led me here. No occurrences found. Although technically the calculator is still correct without the tax mentions, it might be a good idea to compare how much the developer really gets "in cash" so to say, because someone might want to use this calculator as a supplement in consideration for choosing the country for the next job opportunity that offers relocation. What's the point to move to the country where your salary might be up, but the tax will be so high that you get less in the end?

Comment: That would be incredibly complicated. Tax is very complicated and try and replicate this for multiple countries would be a lot of work. Just use a [salary calculator](https://www.thesalarycalculator.co.uk/)

Comment: There's no way they can predict every possible combination of your net pay; that is dependent on tax withholdings which vary by country, state/region, personal withholdings, company offerings, etc. most of which are not published.

Comment: That would definitely be extremely hard to do, as the tax system is well complicated in every country, so it would take an army of employees just to watch the legislation in each country and update the amount to be extracted in the back-end of the calculator. You can use tax calculators for this: https://www.income-tax.co.uk - UK, https://www.taxformcalculator.com -US , https://www.ato.gov.au/Calculators-and-tools/Host/?anchor=STC&anchor=STC#STC/questions - AU, http://www.ey.com/ca/en/services/tax/tax-calculators-2017-personal-tax -
 CA, etc

Comment: Indeed, exebook raises a good point. Comparing take home pay after tax is really important especially between locations that have very different income tax systems. Like others have said, this isn't easy to do though. Fortunately, there are tools available that can handle this. Something like this set of [income tax and salary calculators](https://investomatica.com/income-tax-calculator) works really well in providing fairly good estimates under the most common scenarios.

Answer (score -1):

Just a quick bug report. Seeing that the server side validation of "Years of experience" looks like as: *should be greater than zero*. But the maximum value you guys check for is: 2147483647 (int32 max value), which I suppose is a tiny bit high... given that someone being more than two billion years old might have some unexpected side effects.

To reproduce this, just pass int32 max value to the `ex` GET parameter like:

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/salary?ff=1&dr=FullStackDeveloper&l=Germany&ed=0&ex=2147483647

Comment: *[if you run into any bugs with the new calculator, please post here on Meta Stack Overflow and tag it with bug and salary-calculator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356746/announcing-the-new-salary-calculator)*

Comment: Done as requested.

Answer (score -1):

The middle figure I was given was 70% above what I was getting.  Are these salaries actually paid, as opposed to advertised?  How much should I take off the estimate because I'm not in London?  How much should I take off the estimate because I'm female?

Answer (score -1):

There is no currency specified in my results. Since I work in Sweden I assume I got the result in SEK but it's not completely obvious (although if it's EUR/GBP/USD then I'm seriously underpaid ;) )

Answer (score -10):

I am not an employee even though I have asked my friends about this salary calculator and the numbers are far too high according to them

They are telling that there is  no chance getting at-least the numbers mentioned in the less than 25 percentile category

I strongly believe that there is something wrong in this I have also tested up for myself and asked about the outcomes to many people and all of them strongly disagree with the figures shown up in the Salary Calculator

I have asked this about 20 people who are very much professional and experts in certain technologies like android and React

Comment: Some insights in why you say that would be nice. Which area, which field, what education. Simple saying "I asked 20 people and they earn less" is not really a good guideline.

Comment: So Is this data true

Comment: This matches my experience. AFAIK, I'm earning very near the top of the salary range in my area for what I do, but the calculator said I was in the bottom 25% percentile. I don't think I've ever seen a job posting in this area for the bottom 25% salary, much less the high end.