# The location selector doesn't let me choose my country

Tags: support, salary-calculator

When I fill in my country, the dropdown doesn't let me choose it:

> [image: screenshot of dropdown]

When I don't choose anything from the dropdown, an error appears:

> We don't support this location. Select a location from the dropdown menu.

Comment: Wait, you mean not everyone lives in the United States? Someone should tell Google...

Comment: Same for the Netherlands. Even "Amsterdam" isn't accepted.

Comment: @Cerbrus plenty of [Holland](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iscAY.png)'s .. :(

Comment: @rene it's the same for Sydneys and Australias they're all based in the US and Canada. Wow way to feel insignificant. Don't know if they were wise it keeping it to such a small part of the world and noteworthy - all in the Northern Hemisphere.

Comment: @YvetteColomb we have to accept we're developing countries ...

Comment: @rene literally :)

Comment: What about Antarctica? Is Google missing any more continents?  I guess there are few users there, (all those Linux penguins?), but still...

Comment: The country is not supported together with the Stackoverflow version that you are currently using. Please upgrade your country.

Comment: When will you include Ruritania, Florin, Guilder, and Derkaderkastan?

Comment: Just another release of something where most of the world doesn't exist and the only important citizens must live in a handful of countries.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Currently, we only support a handful of countries based on the availability of significant data in the survey results.  You can see the list of countries in the tooltip:

[image]

Which are:

- United States
- Canada
- United Kingdom
- France
- Germany

A more detailed explanation can be found in the "Geography" section of the accompanying blog post: https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/09/19/much-developers-earn-find-stack-overflow-salary-calculator/

If you want to help add additional countries, you can pick one of the supported countries and there's a survey you can fill out on the results page to add your own data.
[image]

Comment: Ah, my enthusiasm got the better of me and I missed the icon. (I also blame bluefeet's announcement a bit, *"You will be able to search salaries for any given role, location, education, experience, and even specific technologies."* ;)

Comment: @Stijn Hey now don't blame me!!!! The blog has all the details about the model :)

Comment: hmm. So I have to apply for VISA to any of the 5 countries and go there and check the salary calculator again. WEIRD

Comment: Please add a link to "Add your salary" on the calculator in order to help unlocking new countries. @bluefeet

Comment: @Cœur Post a feature request asking for that. Otherwise it will be lost in the comments here.

Comment: But the error message states "We don't support this location. Select a location from the dropdown menu" and there is no dropdown menu at all. Please consider either provide dropdown or adjust the error message as now it confuses.