# How to remove New-Button in bar?

Tags: support, top-bar

Since just now there is a [`New` toolbar button](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356746/announcing-the-new-salary-calculator?cb=1), which is completely irrelevant to stackoverflow as Q & A site. It apparently hosts some tool to calculate something not necessarily interesting to most people.

[image]

Question: How to get rid of this button?

Comment: Click on it, and then on the [x] in the popup?

Comment: Oh wow, that works now, but it didn't the first time I tried. Will it come back from time to time now?

Comment: Hopefully not :)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest It will only show up again when a different new feature is announced.

Comment: @JoeFriend Has it been rolled back (noticed some fun JS issues!) as it randomly went away for me before I got a chance to click the [X]

Comment: please, just stick it in the inbox if you want it to create a notification.

Comment: @DavidG Yep working on fixes for the new feature notification

Comment: @KevinB: Oh, please no. We did that a couple years ago and it was a disaster. Most people discovered the inbox item days or even weeks later, so the meta post (I think it was the MIT license thing?) kept getting votes and comments and answers long after it was "new".  I think we ended hacking out the notification if it hadn't been read. Turns out only a minority of users log into the site frequently most users don't bother to look at their inbox. The inbox (even if we fiddled with the persistence rules) is the wrong medium for this sort of message.

Comment: and an irritating box in the header that requires you to click it *even if you have already been to the article* is better?

Comment: @KevinB: I think it was buggy. So no. That's in no way better.

Comment: @JonEricson It was ToS adjustment about scraping profile information, not MIT. Not that I prefer inbox notifications, but most of the problems wouldn't occur if the link pointed to a blog post -- as it would in this case.

Comment: @Jon Maybe I'm missing something, but why is it so bad that the meta post kept getting votes, comments, and answers long after it was new? Whether it was a ToS or a license adjustment, it still affects all users on the network, and whether they're active every day or only once a month, they should still have the right (and, in fact, be encouraged) to weigh in with their thoughts. It seems the inbox is the *perfect* medium for this sort of message. If it's important enough everybody sees it, then everybody should see it. if it isn't, don't force it down our throats.

Comment: @CodyGray: I forgot the [crux of the story](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278688/users-with-1-rep-cant-view-any-questions-here-on-mse). Turns out meta is not a great place to be lost in.

Comment: @JonEricson I think you meant to link [Sudden increase in off-topic posts on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278562)

Comment: There's really nothing wrong with encouraging folks to visit meta, @Cody - that's not really the issue with using the inbox. The most critical issue is simply that there's no way to turn it *off*: I tracked unread inbox messages for literally months after the last broadcast, and at some point it just wasn't falling off anymore; unless we're limiting the use of this to maybe once a year or less, it's a good bet that eventually a significant number of people would be signing into the site to find that their inbox was completely full of new feature announcements.

Comment: @Shog9 Okay, that makes sense. So the obvious solution to me would be to have the devs write some code to implement a special type of notification message that could be removed from the inbox once it expired. I realize that's a non-trivial exercise, but it still seems like a more appropriate place to deliver notifications, and certainly a lot better than a "NEW" badge in the topbar (which some developer had to implement anyway, since it didn't already exist, either). It doesn't seem all that novel of an idea. The moderator inbox can already get special "orange" notifications, for example.

Comment: For permanently making it stay gone, a quick `@-moz-document domain("stackoverflow.com") {
  .unread-feature-notice{display:none !Important;}
}` in Stylish or something similar in your favorite per-site CSS addon will make it disappear

Comment: That's essentially what we did - manually - for the ToS announcement, @Cody. It worked, eventually (we can't expire emails, so some number of people who'd set that up still got the message late, and the API has no notion of expired inbox items). Seems like an awful lot of work just to abuse a function that was never meant for that purpose. Irritatingly, we could totally use the bulletin board for this (since it WAS built for this purpose) except that you don't see it if you're not logged in, a seemingly benign decision made years ago that has bitten us in the rear numerous times since.

Comment: I marked this a duplicate so we can keep feedback focused in one place.

Answer (score -7):

The new feature notification will dismiss on a per-campaign basis, but it looks like there are a few bugs which are preventing it from working as planned. We will reenable it when it is fixed.

Comment: Could you instead just reenable it on the Jobs site? I have absolutely no interest in the Jobs stuff, and getting notified about updates for Jobs stuff on the Q&A portion of the site is rather annoying.

Comment: @TinyGiant It's nothing to do with jobs, it's a general "here's a new thing" link

Comment: Well if it's a "here's a new Jobs thing" then it should only be shown on Jobs. If it's a "here's a new Q&A thing" then it should be shown on Q&A. I shouldn't be force fed crap about Jobs (this is about the salary calculator at the moment which has everything to do with Jobs and nothing to do with Q&A). @DavidG

Comment: @TinyGiant I think you're being overly harsh here. It's likely to appear very infrequently and it's only a simple notification. There's no "force feeding" here. Every day we use this site for free, I think it's pretty reasonable that SO should occasionally suggest new features to us.

Comment: I have no problem with them suggesting new features to us.. what i have a problem with is doing it in such a way that requires action to dismiss it or otherwise leave a big yellow sign in the header.

Comment: @DavidG That's funny because I don't think I am being too harsh, and I do think that a big noisy intrusion in the header advertising a feature that has absolutely nothing to do with Q&A (that you cannot cancel) is an attempt to force-feed these new projects to a userbase who may not care, or even may be annoyed by these changes. The fact that features are being developed every day for these side projects while nothing is being done to improve Q&A irks me quite a bit, and putting that notification in the topbar is like a slap in the face.

Comment: [This is not cool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vy0Q3.png). It is not only deeply annoying that it is there, but it opens as soon as I open the page, which is jarring, and I again have no interest in being force-fed updates about a feature that has no relation to how I use the site, i.e. for Q&A. Please don't force Jobs notifications on Q&A users. It's great to hear that nothing we've said here has been taken to heart.