# Remove the "new" from the topbar

Tags: bug

I've seen the [Announcing the New Salary Calculator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356746/announcing-the-new-salary-calculator) post and that's nice, I've clicked on it and the results are quite impressive. But since the <kbd>new</kbd> isn't new anymore, could we remove it from the topbar? Or name it properly like `Salary info` or something?

[image]

Comment: Did you refresh the page?  After I clicked on it and refreshed it went away.  Unless they just removed it.

Comment: @NathanOliver it seems they removed it...