# Jobs "role" categories woefully inadequate

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

I'm been working in tech for 30 years and have taken many a "role" as SO labels them. However, none of the job roles come close to describing what I do or have done as a software engineer. I write systems code, network infrastructure code, low-level libraries and drivers, computationally intensive scientific, modeling and simulation software, robotics, IoT, machine learning, computer vision, etc. These are not "desktop apps."

Surprisingly, even the US Department of Labor Statistics does a better job of categorizing software engineers with their SOC codes (see below). This classification is very outdated, but it's better than SO's. I can call myself a "Software Developers, Systems Software" and that would be close enough. Under SO scheme I really don't fit in any category.

```
15-1100 Computer Occupations
  15-1110 Computer and Information Research Scientists
    15-1111 Computer and Information Research Scientists
  15-1120 Computer and Information Analysts
    15-1121 Computer Systems Analysts
    15-1122 Information Security Analysts
  15-1130 Software Developers and Programmers
    15-1131 Computer Programmers
    15-1132 Software Developers, Applications
    15-1133 Software Developers, Systems Software
    15-1134 Web Developers
  15-1140 Database and Systems Administrators and Network Architects
    15-1141 Database Administrators
    15-1142 Network and Computer Systems Administrators
    15-1143 Computer Network Architects
  15-1150 Computer Support Specialists
    15-1151 Computer User Support Specialists
    15-1152 Computer Network Support Specialists
  15-1190 Miscellaneous Computer Occupations
    15-1199 Computer Occupations, All Other
```

Comment: So my role is Software Architect what would additionaly fit is Backend developer, but my main job is being an Architect, why can't i chose that? So you are absolutely right, there are some roles missing

Comment: The current job roles are very SaaS/Cloud focused.

Comment: Where's the role data architect?

Comment: I'm sure people would love hiring me: The "Computer occupations, all other".

Answer (score 14):

This is a very good point and something that needs to be improved in corporations. It's hard pinning down jobs when the job title says one thing, the description says something else, and the actual job is very different from both when you talk to the hiring manager.

Part of this is what we joke about at work as the "HR Industrial Complex". HR departments are often forcing hiring managers into narrow definitions of job titles and don't have appropriate technical training to even begin to understand how any of this stuff works. They struggle to understand that there are hundreds of protocols, software packages, languages, and systems that all vary in their scope and functionality.

An experienced software engineer can simultaneously fit under 10 different job titles in a specific role and have broad experience and understanding beyond "what they did" for a specific job. It's very different from hiring a Marketing and Communications Director, Sales Manager, or Logistics Coordinator. There's a good general understanding of what those types of jobs involve, but the odd men out that no one seems to fully understand are always the software engineers!

Answer (score 5):

Let me give a bit of background as to *how* the current list of roles was designed, and what drove us to design it this way.

We looked at three metrics:

- **Which roles job-seekers search for**

  - We analyzed keywords typed into Google by job-seekers, as well as keywords typed directly into job search, and identified common roles.
- **Which roles employers hire for**

  - We analyzed job titles on our platform, and identified common roles.
- **Which roles allow us to best match job seekers with job listings**

  - The initial list of roles was based on "developer types". Developer types were crafted with the purpose of mapping developer types to visitors, in order to serve relevant job ads.
  - You can see the process that was used to come up with the list of "developer types" in [this great post](https://kevinmontrose.com/2015/01/27/providence-machine-learning-at-stack-exchange/) (TL;DR: "by looking at a lots and lots of résumés and job postings")

We selected roles which verified all of these criteria:

- A significant portion of job seekers search for jobs with this role
- A significant portion of job listings have this role

  - This also requires us to be able to automatically assign this role to job listings, which is currently done by analyzing the job title and description/requirements.

**If you have ideas on how to change to the [current list of roles](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/directory/jobs-by-role) to make it more adequate, please make suggestions! We'll look at it.**

Comment: I think you should add "Software Engineer" and/or "Software Developer" to your list of roles, but that's just me...

Comment: @enderland Just to clarify: many roles currently already are "software engineer" roles (backend developer, mobile developer, etc). Are you suggesting a "parent" role that encompasses all software engineering roles?

Comment: @AurélienGasser, I think this is an example of how a purely data-driven classification system can be inferior to a human curated classification system. The problem is that your algorithm found a bias toward one particular software development role structure and adopted that structure. It is currently a popular way to breakdown roles in a segment of the software industry, but by no means is it the _only_ way. It is simply not generic enough.

Comment: A software engineer is more than just being one type of developer. I for one, consult with users and write use cases, analyze the use cases and come up with a design, do the actual coding, unit test and help in the deployment. I also try to develop an idea where the product should be going in the future. A lot more than just development. I guess this also includes being a "full stack" developer because I write the web pages, service layer and data access layer code.

Comment: Making the role more generic is not going to help with job matching. Perhaps a hierarchy would be better. There is also ambiguity to consider e.g. are programmer, software engineer, developer the same thing? The only vaguely related roles I can choose are `data scientist` and `database administrator`. I work with data scientists but would never claim it. I do some DBA things too but that job title feels anachronistic. My roles are usually described as `data engineer` and sometimes `analytics engineer`. Those should be added, as should `data analyst` and `machine learning engineer`.

Comment: Another common role that should be added: `business intelligence developer`