# Salary Calculator Email

Tags: support, email, salary-calculator

I got an email from SO this morning asking me to check out the [Salary Calculator](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/salary).

Now being a regular user, I'd already seen the [Salary Calculator announcement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356746/announcing-the-new-salary-calculator) via the [New Feature Announcement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356853/announcement-new-feature-notification/), which [I still dislike](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356862/57475), but I digress.

Does using the Salary Calculator not record that I'd already seen and tried it? Or is it a separate system completely?

I know SO wants to drive people to [jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs), but I would have expected not to be notified by email about something I'd already tried. My profile does have **Features & Announcements** emails turned on, which is why I got the email, but this is old news for regular users, so perhaps your emailing targeting could have be improved to not notify people that have already accessed the feature?

Comment: I would love to discuss our mutual dislike of the salary calculator (which happens to also be based on truncated data), but I removed the discussion tag here since this seems to mostly be support and would lend itself to having an answer from an authoritative source rather than a discussion about the tool itself.

Comment: @TravisJ that's fine, I was just feeling lonely, wanted someone to talk to :-(

Comment: All these irrelevant emails from SO recently keep making me turn off all my email preferences one by one...

Comment: @AshleyMedway ha, that's exactly what I did after getting this email.

Comment: I don't see the purpose of this email ever going out to a user that has been active at all recently with how irritating the "new feature" feature is.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Stack Overflow does not have a marketing-automation system that automatically tracks every page you visited and that can trigger or suppress email in response to whether or not you visited certain pages.

We could have manually coded real-time events from our website to our email-marketing system to alert us that individual users had visited the page. Based on your comments, perhaps we should have.

Why didn't we?

1. **We didn't think of it.** You are right that we should have thought harder and tried harder not to annoy our regular users. Based on your comments, we will definitely consider adding functionality like this for future campaigns.
2. **We originally planned to send the email earlier**, when fewer people would have seen the Salary Calculator already. But we pushed the email campaign out for a few weeks while we fixed some bugs. And this, of course, increased the number of users who discovered the Salary Calculator on the site before receiving the email.

As a member of the Stack Overflow marketing team, I can say frankly that we walk a fine line between oversharing and making sure you hear about new features. We use a variety of marketing channels to try to reach developers wherever they happen to be.

In the course of spreading the word, sometimes we reach you more than you want to be reached or we reach you on channels, like email, you no longer want to be reached on.

If you find our emails irrelevant, shame on us. You are absolutely right to [unsubscribe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current).

Comment: Thanks for the response, I wasn't overly annoyed by the email, it's more the calculator in general that I dislike. I assumed that it may have logged that I had run the calculator somewhere and you could have used that info. Your explanation about the delay makes sense, seems like something that should have been sent out a while ago where it would have been more applicable to a larger share of the user base.

Comment: but you do know if we visited the calculator page as the *new* in the menu bar disappears. I think more specifically too, I have my jobs emails turned off before this was sent out, and this is a jobs email.