# Verify if Salary Calculator mail is genuine

Tags: support, spam

Today I got an email about the salary calculator which, according to [Salary Calculator Email](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358024/salary-calculator-email) is indeed from Stack Overflow.

Yet, with this email address I am not a registered user.

Does this mean that Stack Overflow started sending unsolicited emails? How can I verify how Stack Overflow got hold of this address?

Comment: A screenshot of the mail may be helpful... Afaik, an email about the salary calculator _was_ sent out...

Comment: That email is from Stack Overflow. The duplicate should have all your questions answered.

Comment: I took the liberty of changing the title. Suggesting that SO might spam, could be a downvote magnet. I believe the new title is more neutral.

Comment: check your mailing preferences: https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current and have you ever had a different account on the site that might have used that email if this account doesn't? Features & Announcements - was the flag responsible for this email I believe.

Comment: The title was: "[Salary Calculator] What are your skills worth?" and it looked like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIDwa.png if that's of any use to you?!

Comment: @S.L.Barth not sure if you were referring to my comment above yours, the title I was referring to was the subject on the email I received.

Comment: @Tanner Ah, I see. I thought it was in response to my comment about my edit, and that there might have been a misunderstanding. Seems the only person misunderstanding was me :-)

Comment: I think this is not a duplicate after my change of the question.
Apart from this, I tried to "recover" the password for that email and there was none set, but the profile seemed to exist. I deleted it now and hope it is really gone.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by: _I tried to "recover" the password for that email and there was none set, but the profile seemed to exist. I deleted it now_. what password did you try to recover? for SO or for an email account? and what did you delete? an old SO account?

Comment: Sorry, I initiated a stackoverflow password recovery using that email account. I got the recovery email, meaning the account was indeed sometime registered. But it had never had a password. At least that's  the recovery procedure said at some point. I gave the initial password, logged in and then immediately deleted the stackoverflow profile. This way I should not get any surprise emails on that email account from SO any more.