# Salary calculator should not allow me to choose unsupported countries

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs, salary-calculator

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/salary

What is the point of allowing to choose any countries if only several are supported?

This is the kind of stuff that is annoying user experience.

I'm greeted with a big NEW button that gives the impression that I'm about to see something awesome just to be told in an error message that I can't use the feature in the country I'm in.

I even have my location set up in the profile, so it's not like SO doesn't have the means to filter out who gets the "big news".

Oh, and how come I got the NEW button just now anyway? Looks like [it's a year old feature](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356746/announcing-the-new-salary-calculator)

Comment: It probably shows the `new` indicator because they [made changes to it](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/09/05/developer-salaries-in-2018-updating-the-stack-overflow-salary-calculator/?cb=1), including new countries. But indeed, I also got the "your country is not supported" when I tried it.