# "We like this job for you" algorithm location matching?

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

It seems like I'm getting Canadian job recommendations. I'm in Texas, but my laptop's VPN is in Canada. Is it just a coincidence, or are you matching me for jobs using my IP address, rather than my profile information?

PS: I'm not relocating.

Comment: This was reported quite some time ago.  I think they have your info from your profile but they default to your IP Address location.  They should prefer the profile first if it is not empty.  If its empty use the IP address.

Comment: Right now, we use _both_ the last-login IP address _and_ the locations in your profile for job recommendations.  The algorithm does not currently "prefer" either location.  Tomorrow, we're discussing changing how that mechanism works, after which I should be able to post a more proper answer to your question.

Comment: @Andrew: Some feedback for that discussion: 1) Please at least change it so you can opt out of the ip-based method. Serving people ads from country X, when they've explicitly indicated they're only interested in jobs from country Y, benefits neither the employers, users, or SO. It's in fact *really* annoying. 2) You say both are used, but that seems somewhat broken. On the site, I've never seen job ads for my country. On the "This week's top job matches" emails, I used to get lots of relevant matches in my country until February; after that I've gotten none - they're all in my "ip-country" now

Comment: Relevant: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317071/why-is-looking-for-a-job-so-obsessed-with-london

Comment: Use a VPN to _fake_ your location... at your _real_ location. [this comment was posted from International Space Station... now where are those NASA ads?]

Comment: @Andrew _There is no matching_ or it is horribly, horribly broken. The adverts repeatedly suggest countries very far from my profile location _and_ my IP. It wants me to move to other side of a continent and apply to jobs I'm not qualified for, in languages I don't speak.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We on the Jobs team discussed this issue (among others) today.  We will be changing how your location is determined for email purposes soon, in that we will only be using your last-login IP address when you have not specified one or more locations in your [job preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current).

Currently, the job-recommendations algorithm for email uses your last-login IP alongside any locations you specify.  We had already been discussing how this mechanism might not make sense, citing concerns like yours.  So, we'll be changing it.

Note that the algorithm differs for job *ads* that you see on the site (as opposed to job-related *emails*).  Job ads use your current IP address to help determine which jobs to display.  These ads do not (yet) take your job preferences into account — that's on the TODO list, but it has not quite made it to the top of the queue.

Thank you for your feedback!  We appreciate hearing from you.

Answer (score 1):

Believe me, there is absolutely no matching what so ever. Or if there is, whoever wrote it is the most incompetent dev you'll ever meet.

SO does *not* look where you live or where you might be interested in working. Me and my IP number both live in Sweden. Right now, SO tells me too that I'm probably interested in jobs in Montreal and San Francisco. As well as Austria- the whole advert is in German.

Comment: This directly contradicts [Andrew's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357894/we-like-this-job-for-you-algorithm-location-matching#comment523196_357894) stating that we _do_ look at location (profile and last seen IP) for matching. I'm sorry that you feel that we're doing a poor job of that, and we are working to fix it / make it better, but your answer here is just completely incorrect.

Comment: @TimPost I don't _feel_ that you are doing a poor job. Didn't I just say that the site suggests me to move to Canada or go learn German? This isn't the fifth time I point out how horribly buggy this is either, more like the 10th.

Comment: I'm having trouble reproducing these results with your account.  If I look at the jobs we would recommend for you today, they all appear to be in Sweden.  If we look at the job ads you would see elsewhere on the site, same thing.  So, I'm trying to track down this bug... where exactly are you seeing the bad results?  We'd like to fix this issue.

Comment: @Andrew Just now, I type stackoverflow.com then check the job adverts on the side. https://screenshots.firefox.com/U42NdCR42nLoNTbF/stackoverflow.com. As you can see, one job in Germany, one in Sweden, one in California (remote) and one in Montreal. In addition to the advert being all over the place, it suggests that I should work with things like Javascript - which I have never written a single line of code in. My participation in some of the tags suggested is next to zero.

Comment: Man, they finally gave you a job in Sweden, and then you complain it isn't relevant to your expertise? What exactly do you want here?! I have the same problem, by the way. Jobs ads are constantly recommending Javascript and Python jobs to me, even though *nothing* in my profile suggests that I would be interested in or qualified for these jobs. It happened before I was elected moderator, when I hadn't even *visited* a question with one of these tags (they've been on my "ignored tags" list since forever). I figure this is just because that's what 90% of the jobs available are.

Comment: Thank you for providing the screenshot.  Clearly, we have some work to do here.  I can at least see how you might have received these jobs, though -- the two farthest from you either allow remote or visa sponsorship.  Right now, the ad algorithm doesn't account for whether you would be interested in remote jobs or jobs requiring visa sponsorship, which is something we should address.  As for tags, my understanding is that _any_ tag on the job matching a tag in which you are involved is treated as a positive signal for showing the job -- which could also be improved.

Comment: @CodyGray You describe a scenario that we also need to improve.  If the jobs aren't relevant to you, it would be best if we didn't show them even if there are no alternatives.  Getting this right is a long process, and we're continually working on it.

Comment: I see you don't have any [job preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current) on your profile. Filling those should improve the quality of the jobs we show/send your way significantly.

Comment: @g3rv4 Why are you sending job offers my way if I don't have any preferences set?

Comment: @Lundin you shouldn't be receiving the email this question is about, since you're opted out from them. Are you receiving those? If you are, please forward me the last one (my email is on my profile) and I'll look into why you got it.

Comment: @g3rv4 This was posted in October (before email was live?) and referred to the on-site adverts. Ok so "sending" was the wrong word, why are you displaying irrelevant job adverts on the main site is more accurate.

Comment: @Lundin you can't opt-out of ads, but I'd recommend you using an ad blocker if you don't want to see them. Also, if you set your preferences to "not interested in jobs", then you won't see job recommendations on your profile either. If you were interested in jobs, I'd strongly recommend setting your preferences so that you get better matches.

Comment: @g3rv4 I have an ad blocker. Anyway, the point here is: the site is displaying _completely irrelevant_ adverts.

Comment: @Lundin yes, if you don't have job preferences, the quality of the recommendations is pretty bad.

Comment: @g3rv4 To prove you wrong, I just now set some preferences and one single location. So far the job suggestions in the advert remain just as horrible as before. Maybe it is because of caching, we'll see in a few hours...

Comment: @g3rv4 24 hours later, after setting my location and preferences, the advert says that I should definitely settle for a C# career in Austria or Germany, or perhaps a remote Python programmer job.  Can't blame user, can't blame caching. _Believe me, there is absolutely no matching what so ever._

Comment: @Lundin my bad... [ads don't use the location from your preferences](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317083/920295).

Comment: @g3rv4 Then how come it suggests jobs in Germany, when my IP geolocation says Sweden? How come it suggests C# and Python when my preference says C only (and I don't have any participation in C# or Python tags)?

Comment: @Lundin I don't work on the ads team (I work on the talent team, that owns the "We really like this job" email that the question is about). If you are really interested on the matching done on ads, you should open a new question with the [meta-tag:advertising] tag for somebody with more knowledge to get you answers.

Comment: @g3rv4 Nah, I really don't care, I've proven over and over that the so-called "matching algorithm" is (still) broken. As long as you don't try to sell me "candidate matching job adverts on SO", because that would clearly be false advertising.