# Jobs emails "We really like this job for you" aren't accurate enough

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, email

I received an email sent from SO Jobs titled **We really like this job for you.** The implication is this job (or these jobs) would be good for me. Good for my career.

However, the featured job doesn't look all that good to me, and I didn't opt in for these emails in the first place.

## Here's my feature request:

- Have these emails sent for people who opt in only
- Change the tone: you have no idea if these jobs are "good for [me]". It's just a list of your clients that I hit checkboxes for.

Comment: Regarding not wanting to miss useful emails... This is why we recently broke up email settings into a bunch of more specific ones; [turning off](https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current) "recommended jobs" shouldn't do anything to emails sent for other purposes.

Comment: @Shog9, that's a classic bad response. You're telling me to go and configure something -- you're telling me to go deal with it. I really don't want to. It's more reasonable to not send me something a I have to deactivate if I didn't ask for it. The only reason I invested the time in the post is out of frustration and annoyance. You might as well have suggested I delete my Careers Profile. Because I don't want to deal with it. I doubt I'm alone in finding this added **SPAM** annoying. If you want to test people, go ahead.

Comment: I'm not suggesting either; it's your call what you do or don't do. Merely noting that your concern over missing emails you want by trying to disable emails you don't is something we've [put a fair bit of thought into lately](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298906/control-the-types-of-email-you-receive-via-our-new-email-settings-feature) and tried to make less of a headache. That doesn't mean the defaults are correct or that the emails are well put-together or that the jobs they offer are relevant - those are all separate failure-points and need to be considered independently.

Comment: @Shog9, the message I'm getting is you're unconcerned with the nuisance to me. You're "suggesting" I could go and read about, and configure to remove a nuisance you created. You don't care that it's a nuisance. You're unconcerned that this may be my tipping point to just opting out. I have other channels.

Comment: Well, that last sentence is correct - if you're finding it annoying, patronizing, even slightly irritating... Please, do opt out. There's no reason anyone should have to be pushed to a "tipping point" for that.

Comment: @Shog9, I appreciate the honesty about your apathy. That was very clear.

Comment: Dave, the fact is that Shog9 doesn't work on the Jobs site and really has no control over the emails that it sends out. That's why he didn't post an answer. He did feel like he had some relevant advice to share that might help you out, so he included it in a comment. I'm not sure why you are interpreting his comments in such a negative way. I am having a similar problem with SO Jobs, in that it sends me jobs related to technologies I have never once interacted with on this website and have absolutely no interest in. Yet, I want to continue receiving notifications of *relevant* jobs.

Comment: What he *does* have a point about is that these mails started without our explicit opting in and that sucks. But I'm sure that complaint has been filed elsewhere on Meta already. As to the marketing hyperbole in the mail - meh. Go sue KFC for not being somewhat decent but not Finger Lickin' Good™ first.

Comment: So, you don't want to opt out of receiving those mails for fear of missing useful information, but you want those mails to be only sent to users who opt in? So, would you opt in again, _knowing_ that you would interpret the emails as you do?

Comment: @Cerbrus, that's not really my point. I don't want the spam job suggestions. I don't really want to deal with configuring or opting out of something I never opted in for. I expected more from SO, a better treatment and sensitivity to users. Do I expect too much not to be spammed by emails I never opted in for?

Comment: @CodyGray, honestly, the way shog9 wrote his comments made it sound like he was one of the developers or even leaders on the team. **"we recently broke up email settings into a bunch of more specific ones"** What you're telling me changes the way I see our whole conversation, but I hope you can see the source of confusion. In fact, I don't understand how Shog9 is in any way a part of "we" that did anything in that case. Other people I asked to look at this thread interpreted his words exactly as I did.

Comment: He's on the team that manages the Q&A sites. That's a different team of people than the ones who manage the Jobs site.

Comment: If this has you this worked up; having an email address has to be **sheer torture** for you. The defaults are fine for most users. Dislike these messages? Just opt out. Not that difficult. You can't opt out on having ever received an email, retroactively. That technology doesn't exist, sadly.

Comment: @yivi, have you gone and asked most users what they think? Or are you speaking for yourself and assuming how other people think. I do get SPAMMED a lot and expected better of SO than to add to it.

Comment: @CodyGray, I'm still confused how his words reconcile that he doesn't have a role but used the "we did" in reference to this. Probably a subtlety about internal complexities.

Comment: @Pekka웃, it's the combination of everything that gets annoying. I didn't opt in, please don't be like other bottom feeders and SPAM me. The suggestion to change the language was a well intended critique. If you're gonna SPAM me, at least don't pretend it's somehow good for me. LinkedIn does it so much more professionally, here are positions that seem to match your listed skills. It's less annoying that way. When you SPAM people, does it hurt to take a small step to make the recommendations unoffensive... Like Pekka, we think this job at KFC is good for you. It pays $11/hr!

Comment: Shog is just using "we" in the "the company" sense. Not "we" as in "my team, or me," but a somewhat large "we" that is this 300+ people company, @DaveAlperovich

Comment: @JNat, that's interesting, bc speaking for the company, Shog is suggesting if I have a problem with being SPAMMED I should leave Careers and maybe StackOverflow completely. That telling, and I will take it under advisement. The whole interaction with Shog was more annoying than the emails and as much as I have enjoyed Careers and contributing to SO, I don't want these kinds to deal with that kind of pissing most of all. I was already annoyed enough, Shog is makes leaving feel more tempting.

Comment: Can't help but feel this is an overreaction. Shog didn't suggest you leave the site; he suggested opting out of the E-Mail stuff. No? The complaint "SO shouldn't send out stuff like this without us previously opting in" is valid and I agree (and I also agree they've been on a very slippery slope towards becoming spammy recently, probably out of investor pressure to make money, for which Jobs probably is the only serious channel), but that fits in one short paragraph.

Comment: Shog's suggestion was that you opt out of receiving emails/notifications, should these emails/notifications annoy you, so as to avoid getting you near a tipping point, as you suggested you were getting close to, @DaveAlperovich — Shog never mentioned you should step away from the site because you're feeling spammed :)

Comment: @JNat, maybe I misread it. I was certainly thinking of deleting both rather than enduring more SPAM in my life. I made a point of saying this is sad b/c both relationships I've appreciated. And yes, ppl can feel I'm overreacting, but why should I have to opt out of something I never opted into. Am I wrong to expect that SO is above this kind of thing?

Comment: Someone from the Jobs team will be posting a reply later today, to try to address your concerns, @DaveAlperovich ;)

Comment: `Am I wrong to expect that SO is above this kind of thing?` Up until now, no. But something seems to have changed a bit. We'll see where it leads.

Comment: [annoying banner](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357858/839601) for those who didn't sign up, followed by irrelevant job ads for those who did. Nice

Comment: @Pekka웃, you may be right. We have things that just, added to others, push us over edge. My daily spam is already a daily irritant. And to be told by SO employees that it's no big deal, just stop my day and deal with another thing, cause they don't see it as a big deal was surprising. I've invested more time in venting my frustration than the time it would take to fix this, mostly b/c I thought that SO was the kind of organization that didn't want to be associated with such low brow activities. Instead I'm told to go fix it myself and what's the BFD. I expect this from Facebook, not SO

Comment: _"stop my day and deal with another thing"_: I'm pretty sure you've invested significantly more time in complaining about this feature, than the time it would take to disable email notifications once and for all.

Comment: @Cerbrus, admittedly, I have. As I pointed out countless times, I invested the time in venting b/c I really thought SO was above this kind of thing. Once someone tells me I'm wrong (as Shog seemed to) I'll weigh the possibility of deleting all accounts.

Comment: FWIW, I spoke up because of a concern in the initial revision of this post to the effect of not wanting to disable these emails lest you miss notifications you wanted; until fairly recently, that was very much a concern (for a big chunk of the 9 years SO has been around, there was a single checkbox on profiles with little explanation for what it did; that was replaced a couple years ago with a confusing split of preferences attached to Jobs - only in the past few months have you been able to separate "job offers" from "job alerts").

Comment: To your core concern: even when enabled, these emails should be *rare* - I have over a dozen accounts with this option enabled and haven't seen more than maybe 1 of these emails across all of them. I don't think anyone at the company wants us to become like LinkedIn, whose emails clog my inbox in spite of the fact that I've never indicated any interest whatsoever in job-hunting there... So if you're getting badly-targeted emails, something is not working as it should be; someone from the Jobs team is looking into that & should be able to provide more relevant info once they've finished.

Comment: @Shog9, i wish I could upvote your comment +12. I'll just serial up vote your posts discretely using puppets and friends I can push around ;)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Thank you for your feedback. This is really valuable to help us ensure these emails don’t feel like spam. Our goal is to be relevant and useful.

I’m tagging this post as status-planned because we are actively working on improving messaging and recommended jobs for this email.

**Regarding opt in:** this email is only sent to users who are subscribed to the ‘Recommended Jobs’ email list and have a job search status set to ‘Actively Looking’ or ‘Open’.  There are additional job recommendation criteria in place for this specific email, so even if you’re opted in, you may not receive an email every week if there isn’t a job that meets the criteria.

**Regarding job recommendations:** we made a few changes recently to improve the relevance of this email:

- We stopped sending to users who did not have a job search status of ‘active’ or ‘passive’.  Before this change, users who engaged with jobs (ran a search, viewed a job, etc) but had a null status could have received this email.
- We updated location logic to prioritize the location on your profile first. If there is no location, then we fall back to your IP.  Before this change, we gave [equal weight to your profile and IP](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357894/we-like-this-job-for-you-algorithm-location-matching).
- We implemented a salary filter so that we aren’t recommending jobs below your salary requirement. You can set this in your job preferences.
- We implemented a seniority filter so that we aren't recommending jobs outside of your desired seniority range. This can also be set in job preferences.

We still have some work to do. Here’s what we have slated for the near term:

- Update the [underlying algorithm](https://medium.com/@aurelien.gasser/a-dive-into-stack-overflow-jobs-search-62bc6e628f83). We’re working with our data team to refresh the weights we use to match jobs to users. This is something we’re constantly testing.
- Incorporate more [job preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current) as filters so that you don’t receive recommendations that don’t align with the info you gave us: you should be able to quickly filter out categories of jobs that you’re simply never going to be interested in.
- Improve messaging: opting in and out of features should be really clear and easy to do. I hear your point about tone. We’ll be looking at that too.
- Something we’re discussing is how we might be able to include the values used to make a recommendation (your job prefs) so you have more insight into why you’re receiving a particular recommendation.

Anita [said it best](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358024/salary-calculator-email/358098#358098), if you find our emails irrelevant, shame on us. You are absolutely right to [unsubscribe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current).

**More background info:**

The “Recommended Jobs” email list used to be called  “Jobs New Features.” It was renamed when we launched the [updated email preference center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298906/control-the-types-of-email-you-receive-via-our-new-email-settings-feature). We felt this naming better represented the purpose of this list - to promote jobs and companies. The reason we maintained a separate Jobs promotional list (it was almost merged with the ‘New Features and Announcements’) was to give you a way to unsubscribe from jobs stuff but still receive updates on big Stack Overflow announcements.  New users must opt into this email list (as well as the “Features and Announcements” promotional list).

I left out a lot of detail on the additional criteria we put in place to send this email. If you have more questions about it, I’m happy to answer, just let me know.

**UPDATE**: all of the items listed above under "here's what we have slated for the near term" have been implemented.

Answer (score 0):

> *Have these emails sent for people who opt in only*

I disagree. You can't expect new users to go into their profile and manually *enable* e-mails like this.
Users may not even consider the possibility these mails exist, when they're not familiar with the site.

Opt-out is how (almost) all large sites do it. Why should SE deviate from the norm?

> *Change the tone. You have no idea if these jobs are "good for [me]". It's just a list of your clients that I hit checkboxes for.*

The jobs are selected based on criteria *you* entered. They are the best fit the system finds, based on your input.
SE isn't telling you they expect you to be paid poorly. They're not trying to insult you.
This is just a simple script that grabs a few jobs. Don't iterpret that as more than *"just a list of clients that you hit checkboxes for."*

This is just like the dutch version of ebay telling me I may be interested in a toy motorcycle after searching for motorcycles. They're not telling me I'm a child. The system is just a computer: naive.

Comment: People can disagree. I didn't opt in for this SPAM. I don't want it, and if you pay attention to the comments, people find them annoying. I don't want to deal with this, configure it, or anything. It doesn't seem like much to ask, not to be spammed without opting in for this. I expect better from SO. I expect their standards to be higher. I don't want to be bothered with the "child's annoyance. Expectations incorrect.

Comment: As much as you consider those mails "spam", they're not. They're part of a product you registered for. A part you can chose to disable. That said, you're constantly complaining about "spam", but you've stated you don't _want_ to disable the mails. You expect the site to change because you are getting annoyed by a feature you refuse to disable. I'm sorry, but you're going to have to come up with a better reason for the site to change than that.

Comment: That argument can be adopted by a product and service I want no part of. If this is the thinking that drives Careers and SO, I don't have time or patience for it and want out. I'm surprised b/c I expect more from SO than from "Dutch Ebay"

Comment: I'm just saying that _"Change this feature because I don't like it"_ isn't a good feature request. Nor is _"I expect more"_. Please take a step back, and take a moment to come up with some _rational_ arguments against having the emails as "opt-out"

Comment: And I'm just saying "opt out of this SPAM if you don't like it" is below my expectations of SO. I'm getting some indications I expected too much. When Facebook does it, I don't bother posting anything to them. It's F-ing Facebook. We're at an impasse. Polar opposite views. I get that you don't see at as a big deal.

Comment: _<...> is below my expectations of SO._ Okay, but that's not a feature request. That's venting frustration. That's a rant. Don't get me wrong, I don't like the emails. I immediately disabled them the moment I got one. I just don't understand what you expect to get out of this question, lacking rational arguments to change how the site works...

Comment: We're just at an impasse. I suggest feature changes. My reasoning is that the current MO is low brow. If we take this any further, we'll just go through the circle more.

Comment: I thought y'all had reached the conclusion that you were just going in circles? :) maybe we can just drop the conversation, since it isn't going anywhere productive, really? :)

Comment: @JNat, I thought so too ;)

Comment: I mean... if this is opt-in by default i'd be annoyed by that too, especially if there wasn't a checkbox on the signup page to disable it immediately. But i don't know if that's the case. Job suggestions without asking for them IS ads/spam.