# Why does Stack Overflow want to know my location?

Tags: support, bug, privacy

I visited [a Stack Overflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32577808/how-to-create-a-new-instance-of-a-struct-in-c) from Google, and this message popped up:

[image]

Why does Stack Overflow need to know my location? Note that I'm using a userscript that only hides the ads, so Stack Overflow doesn't get penalized, but if it was an advertisement requesting this, I would have expected the domain of an advertisement in the message, and not Stack Overflow itself.

Comment: Can you check which ads were served on that page? I do think the ads are added to the DOM, so they are not in an IFRAME so that technically make them come from Stack Overflow if the ad goes rogue.

Comment: I initially though I had a full blown adblocker on, and re-used that tab to go to meta StackOverflow, it doesn't show that popup anymore when I visit that page again

Comment: That makes the suspicion for an sneaky ad even higher.

Comment: @rene actually, there is an iframe. I don't think it's external ads, more likely something they put in SO For Teams code, maybe by mistake. (Hence not many can reproduce)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I've got Teams and can't reproduce.

Comment: @ShadowWizard while ads are indeed loaded inside an <iframe> element, this iframe's document get populated by script and still has its origin set to stackoverflow.com. You can try from your dev-tools to switch the js console's context to the one of such iframe (`google_ads_iframe_...`)  and then run `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(()=>{});`. You'll see that the request is made on behalf of stackoverflow.com, just like in the screenshot. It can still very well be a sneaky ad.

Comment: mmh let me guess: Netherlands?

Comment: @Kaiido well, in such case SE should block ads from using JS. Not that it will happen, but they should. :)

Comment: @wizzwizz4 assuming it's a single ad, it takes about 200 reloads to get to it.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre You're indeed correct ( I didn't realise the message was Dutch, I just automatically translate posts texts I read in my head to my universal language )

Comment: @Ferrybig I think you should add [meta-tag:bug] to the tags, and [meta-tag:privacy], and maybe [meta-tag:security].

Comment: @ShadowWizard I could not agree more, if they gone as far as asking our address, I worry what else data they grabbed about us...

Comment: @Kaiido IP address for sure (well, anyone can get it by posting image pointing to their server, but still..)

Comment: I've never seen this request. Has anyone else seen it apart from FerryBig?

Comment: I've never been asked by SO for my location. But I don't get ads on SO, so... I also uBlock everything. (I contribute enough; don't need to be tracked for my trouble)

Comment: @MartinSmith I've seen it on mobile web page today.

Comment: @ayhan are you signed up for SO teams?

Comment: @MartinSmith I am also signed in to SO teams

Comment: @MartinSmith No. And the mobile page doesn't show ads as far as I know.

Comment: Also do you have any recent browser extensions or userscripts installed? They could also request for the location.

Comment: This happened to me using Meta on Dec 24 using my Pixel in Chrome. Took a screenshot but I never got around to posting because it was the holidays. I haven't been able to reproduce since then. https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSDVr.png

Comment: I think it is for For advertising,

Comment: You should have screenshotted the whole page not just the angle showing the popup...

Comment: SO job adverts seem to be location sensitive, that can be one genuine reason for SO to know the location.

Comment: @peeyushsingh a little more than a year ago that supposedly only used the IP: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357894/we-like-this-job-for-you-algorithm-location-matching (from the accepted answer): "Job ads use your current IP address"

Comment: @peeyushsingh here we are talking about GPS precision coords, what kind of genuine reason is there for an ad to know where I am with a ten feet precision?

Comment: We don't ask. I'm trying to determine why you're seeing this. Does it repro with extensions disabled?

Comment: @SamuelLiew No recent installations of new tooling, I was just coding for fun, trying to research a new language, and suddenly, 1 visit to a question out of many to SO gave this popup

Answer (score 23):

I'm trying to help debug in comments, but for all:

> Why does Stack Overflow want to know my location?

***We don't***. This is a rogue extension or ad most likely and we'll get to the bottom of it.

Comment: I don't think it was a rouge extension. I had this happen using the mobile version of Meta on Chrome for Android which doesn't allow extensions. And the TLS certificate was valid over my home network via Verizon FiOS. MITM is highly unlikely as well. (I have faith SO is not asking for this data directly. Just adding more information to help.)

Comment: @StevenV Thanks, that definitely helps. We're look at our options to both track this down and kill it now.

Comment: I also have the suspicion it is an advertisement, I purposely didn't pick an option when it asked for the location, and then I refreshed, it should have asked again in the case of an compromised extension, as those people usually target the sheep, and don't need complicated code

Comment: Can this be a Chrome anomaly? I've seen this the day after SO asked me to use my phone's location: https://imgur.com/a/B1GnHBk

Comment: @NickCraver I got another repro on https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/265083/minecraft-command-to-remove-duplicate-entities but this time I had my adblock (ublock on, since I require it for the distracting animated header on that site) https://i.imgur.com/BBFq8KB.png Again after following a link from Google