# Email about a job in my area is actually on the other side of an ocean

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Last night I received an email alert stating that there was a job in my location. To be honest I was shocked, there has literally never been a job that has triggered this email alert!

I was even more shocked to discover that the job being offered was a [developer job for a multi national stock trading company in Bala](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/161148/software-developer-options-trading-susquehanna-international):

[image: Screenshot of job listing]

Now Bala is a small medieval town in North Wales. I know it well, it's about 30 miles from me, it has a nice lake and (Like pretty much every old town in North Wales) it's own castle.

[image: Wikipedia article about Bala]

I actually genuinely thought for a while that this job was in Bala North Wales (it was early in the morning).

I spent a while reading the spec and then I decided that something didn't add up here. I actually had to Google the company to figure out that this was actually offering a job in a place called Bala Cynwyd (Obviously founded by Welsh settlers this one) which is a district of Philadelphia in **Pennsylvania**... USA!

Now the job sounded interesting but that's quite some commute
[image: Map showing length of commute]
*and I [thought London was bad](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317071/why-is-looking-for-a-job-so-obsessed-with-london) :)

The location does state Bala Cynwyd, PA in the email and on the job itself.

So why did I get this email at all? It's about 1,000 miles outside of my 50 mile alert radius.

I'm guessing it's not just user error (though that would be annoying in itself) as the email does state PA.

Comment: Typical millennial mindset, complaining about the commute and then wondering why they can't find a job!!!!

Comment: Unfortunately I'm too old to fit into a Millennial. I think I'm "Generation X" :)

Comment: I'd advocate to get your travel expenses covered, I think it would be financially wise to do so.

Comment: Well, they do offer paid relocation?

Comment: Which would be great if I had any interest whatsoever in living in America, but I don't. I like living in Wales I'm going to watch the rugby next week, do they even have rugby in America? Heathens. I'd suffer from [hiraeth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiraeth)

Comment: There's a [Chester](https://goo.gl/maps/UZidMbrTQ5k) in Pennsylvania too! Looking into a fix!

Comment: Americans, coming here, stealing all our place names....I bet they even have a Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwllllantysiliogogogoch?! ([actual place near me](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Llanfairpwllgwyngyll))

Comment: I'm presuming that the fact that there is "a fix" means this is a bug. re-tagged accordingly.

Comment: @Liam they have something called [Handegg](http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/001/071/775/c12.jpg) (which they call Football) I hear is popular o'er there...

Comment: I heard they've even got a new version of York over there

Comment: You'll be telling me next that they're stealing the names of [picturesque Lincolnshire towns next](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Boston/@52.9783775,-0.056431,13z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x47d7c2c53856f733:0x8406d541f1a0910c!8m2!3d52.97894!4d-0.026577)

Comment: Did you hear that there's a new South Wales? It's not just on the other side of the ocean.

Comment: OMG, Welsh toponymy is even more fun than German. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welsh_toponymy

Comment: @BilltheLizard Welsh names mostly sound very exotic but translate to really mundane things. My house is called Ty Gwyn (white house) there's a group of mountains called Glyder Fawr (Big pile of stones) and Glyder Fach (small(er) pile of stone) :) You get a lot of Big Hills and End of the road, etc.

Comment: For those interested in how Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwllllantysiliogogogoch sounds, here's a [weather presenter saying it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHxO0UdpoxM). The locals just call it Llanfair P.G.

Comment: @Pekka웃. ummm. this is 2017. how dare you *assume* my commuting habits. I take offense. #MillennialThings

Comment: @BillTheLizard I think you are thinking more of [Austrian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fucking,_Austria) toponymy!

Comment: When you park up for your weekly commute, use Level 9 at Manchester, (UK midlands, not New Hampshire).  It often has spaces and there's a moving walkway to the terminal.  Take your own Welshcakes to eat during the interminable hours crammed in coach.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, the problem stems from that your search for *Chester* resolved to [Chester, PA](https://goo.gl/maps/5gjB2Rd3siv) which is only 22 miles from Bala Cynwyd, PA. That likely happened because when we processed the alerts and geo-coded Chester it only had the server's IP address (which would be located in the US) to use as a region hint.

I've just updated the code to make sure it uses the country code associated with your home location (GB in your case) falling back to wherever you last logged on from.